# How to assert that a cookie was cleared in a rails 3 functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cookies

I would like to write to functional test for one of my rails 3 controllers that asserts that a given cookie gets cleared. I have tried:

```
test "cookie should be cleared" do
  @request.cookies["foo"] = "bar"
  put :clear_foo
  assert @response.cookies["foo"].nil?
end
```

However, this test succeeds even though the controller is a no-op (I have manually confirmed that the cookie persists in my browser when set).

Any ideas?

*<sub>To clarify, this question is about how to test that a cookie gets cleared, not about how to actually clear it.</sub>*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that

```
assert cookies["foo"].nil?
```

does the job. See also Chu Yeow's blog post [*"Some functional testing gotchas in Ruby on Rails"*](http://blog.codefront.net/2006/09/03/some-functional-testing-gotchas-in-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: In functional tests it works. But in integration tests you will not be able to test cookies set in actions.